# Openstreetmap headers and contact infos

Tags: api, http-headers, contacts, openstreetmap

I'm trying setting up headers for Openstreetmap. I use AJAX to send requests.

Which HTTP header field is used for contacts? I thought it was "From" but the request doesn't allow that field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want to send a contact address with your requests for some reason? There isn't really a way in HTTP to do that, but then I'm not sure why you want to - can you explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: from the official page they need your contact email on requests so i tryed using header , finally i used url parameter, so we can close this question, i fixed that

Comment: as usually downvotes and no reasons why ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your clarification about it sounds like you are probably talking about one of our usage policies:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy

The only one which explicitly talks about contact information seems to be the Nominatim one for the geocoder, though all require a valid `User-Agent` header to help us identify any problem users.

The best way to send the contact information requested by the Nominatim policy is probably as part of the `User-Agent` though using a URL parameter will work fine as well - anything that lets the administrators work out who you are from the logs if there is a problem basically.

Comment: Thanks Tom and i hope that Openstreetmap will grow up more and more in time, at the end i'm sending the url param email="myemail@email.em" so i think this  fixes this problem ;)